# How would I know which submit button in JavaScript was clicked from rendered HTML:

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know which button was just clicked and submit the form with its submitbuttonnextstatusid's value.

```
<input type="submit" class="ButtonSm" onclick="this.form.submitbuttonid.value='FlpZTFMaYgVeRGgOc0QOFDRhZikBbnV2H2BZ';this.form.dele.value=0;this.form.submitbuttonnextstatusid.value=25269;this.form.save.value=1;this.form.butaction.value=2;" value="Accounting" id="submitbutton">

<input type="submit" class="ButtonSm" onclick="this.form.submitbuttonid.value='F0l7LUhlZxpRGRc8KhBUHDVUZxIsHgwyH2FY';this.form.dele.value=0;this.form.submitbuttonnextstatusid.value=25264;this.form.save.value=1;this.form.butaction.value=3;" value="Awaiting Dictation" id="submitbutton_25">
```

Comment: Is this the whole HTML? Are these buttons infact child objects to forms? If so just use `.parent('form').submit()`

Comment: These are dynamically created button on the fly and I can't change the HTML. I need the statusid to submit the form with that status id and the value I am interested is submitbuttonnextstatusid.

Comment: What does the form look like? Is the StatusId a `data-` attribute, the actual `id` or something else.

Comment: I should have used "submitbuttonnextstatusid" instead of StatusId. I need to extract the value of "submitbuttonnextstatusid" of the button just clicked and submit the form with that value(submitbuttonnextstatusid)

Comment: I have create a [jsFiddle where you can see an option](http://jsfiddle.net/Joqus/TtGE2/).

Comment: You are doing it by class "ButtonSm" but my page contains this class at my other locations which will submit the form which I don't want.

Comment: @user3047229 use the selector that fits your needs

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#submitbutton").click(function(){

// post data with id 25269
});

$("#submitbutton_25").click(function(){

// post data with id 25264
});
```

If you are adding buttons dynamically, use ".on()" instead of ".click()".

Comment: This doesn't help him submit a specific form, just fires off a function